# Modelling of C++ concepts with Scala traits

Tags: scala, c++-concepts

There are some examples of using Scala traits like C++ concepts and Haskell type classes in paper [«Type Classes as Objects and Implicits»](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~bruno/papers/TypeClasses.pdf&ei=ffolUfi9Ke_74QTGw4HIBw&usg=AFQjCNFaTZEDANpHGRPiCQk0mrW2ib3o3A&sig2=1RbzhD6h2lAKPwJxzbV02Q&bvm=bv.42661473,d.bGE). I try to write something like `InputIterator` concept and `find` function in Scala:

```
concept InputIterator<typename Iter> {
  typename value_type;
  value_type operator*(Iter);
  ...
};

template<typename Iter, typename V>
requires InputIterator<Iter> && EqualityComparable<Iter::value_type, V>
Iter find(Iter first, Iter last, V v) { 
    while (first < last && *first != v)
        ++first;
    return first;
}
```

I'm not sure I understand traits correctly. But still... There is `InputIterator` trait written in Scala (or more exactly — it's simplified analogue with methods used in `find` function):

```
trait InputIterator[Iter] {
    type value_type

    def <(a: Iter, b: Iter): Boolean
    def ++(it: Iter): Unit
    def *(it: Iter): value_type
}
```

`EqualityComparable` is clear:

```
trait EqualityComparable[S, T] {
    def ==(s: S, t: T): Boolean
    def !=(s: S, t: T): Boolean = !(s == t)
}
```

But what should we do with `find`? I would like to write something like this:

```
def find[Iter, V](first: Iter, last: Iter, x: V)(implicit iterator: InputIterator[Iter], 
    cmp: EqualityComparable[iterator.value_type, V]): Iter =
{
    while (iterator.<(first, last) && cmp.!=(iterator.*(first), x))
        iterator.++(first)
    first
}
```

But it causes an error *«illegal dependent method type»*. And I don't know how to «extract» abstract type `value_type` other way. So as a result I have got this code:

```
trait EqualityComparable[S, T] {
    def ==(s: S, t: T): Boolean
    def !=(s: S, t: T): Boolean = !(s == t)
}

trait InputIterator[Iter] {
    type value_type

    def <(a: Iter, b: Iter): Boolean
    def ++(it: Iter): Unit
    def *(it: Iter): value_type
}

trait VTInputIterator[Iter, VT] extends InputIterator[Iter] {
    type value_type = VT
}

class ArrayListIterator[T](a: ArrayList[T], i: Int) {
    val arr: ArrayList[T] = a
    var ind: Int = i

    def curr(): T = arr.get(ind)
    def ++(): Unit = { ind += 1 }

    override def toString() = "[" + ind.toString() + "]"
}

class InputIterArrList[T] extends VTInputIterator[ArrayListIterator[T], T]{ 
    def <(a: ArrayListIterator[T], b: ArrayListIterator[T]) = {
      if (a.arr == b.arr) a.ind < b.ind
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException()
    }

    def ++(it: ArrayListIterator[T]): Unit = it.++()
    def *(it: ArrayListIterator[T]) = it.curr()
}

object TestInputIterator extends Application{   

    def find[Iter, VT, V](first: Iter, last: Iter, x: V)(implicit iterator: VTInputIterator[Iter, VT], 
        cmp: EqualityComparable[VT, V]): Iter = 
    {
      while (iterator.<(first, last) && cmp.!=(iterator.*(first), x))
        iterator.++(first)
      first
    }

    implicit object EqIntInt extends EqualityComparable[Int, Int] {
      def ==(a: Int, b: Int): Boolean = { a == b }
    }

    implicit object inputIterArrListInt extends InputIterArrList[Int]{}

    val len = 10;
    var arr: ArrayList[Int] = new ArrayList(len);
    for (i: Int <- 1 to len)
      arr.add(i)
    var arrFirst = new ArrayListIterator(arr, 0)
    var arrLast = new ArrayListIterator(arr, len)
    var r = find(arrFirst, arrLast, 7)
    println(r)
}
```

Instead of abstract type we used type parameter `VT` in `def find[Iter, VT, V]`.

So the question is: how it can be done better? And is it possible to use abstract type `value_type` without additional type parameter `VT`?

Comment: Don't know much about C++, so, why InputIterator isn't just a Iterator?

Comment: In C++ `Iterator` is a base class for iterators, it hasn't got any methods. And `InputIterator` allows you to traverse collection (only for reading).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the signature of find to:

```
def find[Iter, V, II <: InputIterator[Iter]](first: Iter, last: Iter, x: V)(
  implicit iterator: II, cmp: EqualityComparable[II#value_type, V]): Iter
```

That's probably what you want to express.

Note that your Scala code is really not the same as the C++ code. In C++ `find` uses `Iter::value_type` but in Scala you use `InputIterator[Iter]#value_type`.

Comment: And may be there are other ways to define `InputIterator` and `find`? Or only the approach above can be used?

Comment: There's not much point to your `InputIterator` trait, it's simpler to just make your iterators extend an iterator trait instead. Then find will look like `find[Iter <: Iterator, V](first: Iter, last: Iter, x: V)(implicit cmp: EqualityComparable[Iter#value_type, V]): Iter`

Comment: But in such way we'll lose retroactive modelling ability:( On the other hand it may not be so important in this example.

Thank you very much, it's great!